# Changing "Created by:" Event description in Calendar using Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I'm trying to use a Google Form to have customers fill out event details for catering. And no matter who fills out the form, it always shows "Created by: catering@haleyhouse.org". I was wondering if there was anyway to change that to show the email address of the person filling the form out?

This is my code I'm using to create the event from onFormSubmit()

```
//rename data into useable tags  
  timestamp = newRequest[0][0],
  company = newRequest[0][1],
  contact_name = newRequest[0][2],
  contact_email = newRequest[0][3],
  contact_phone = newRequest[0][4],
  onsite_name = newRequest[0][5],
  onsite_phone = newRequest[0][6],
  pickup_delivery = newRequest[0][7],
  day = newRequest[0][8],
  address = newRequest[0][9],
  location = newRequest[0][10],
  parking = newRequest[0][11],
  guests = newRequest[0][12],
  other = newRequest[0][13],
  time = newRequest[0][14];
  date = newRequest[0][15]
  papergoods = newRequest[0][16]

//create new calendar event  
  var dateString = date.toDateString();
  var timeString = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes();
  var endtimeString = (time.getHours() + 1) + ":" + time.getMinutes();
  var timestampFormat = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(timestamp), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm aaa');
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('haleyhouse.org_1oicreouarl3je785ltupuoppg@group.calendar.google.com');
  var event = calendar.createEvent(contact_name + ", " + company + ", " + contact_phone, 
      new Date(dateString + " " + timeString), 
      new Date(dateString + " " + endtimeString), 
      {description: timestampFormat + " received form request - google", location: address});
```

Is there anyway to change this or will it always be by default the email address of the Calendar owner?

Comment: Actually it would be more exact to say it is always created by the owner of the script ! And I think this is obviously not changeable.